# Sorting array given two comparators?

Tags: java, comparison

Say I have two comparators, a primary and a secondary. How can I sort an array first by the primary comparator, then by the secondary?

Say each object has a name and a number field.

Like

```
Bob 1
Bob 2
Jack 1
Jack 2
```

Is it possible without creating a new comparator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish your sort without creating a new comparator.

There is a [well-known trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) for sorting by a primary field, secondary, tertiary, etc: First sort by the least important field (tertiary), then the next important field (secondary), and finally the most important field (primary). But the sorting algorithm needs to be *stable* for this to work.

If you are sorting an array, use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29). If you are sorting a `List`, use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). Both of these methods are guaranteed to be stable.

Suppose your primary comparator object is stored in the variable `primaryComp`, and your secondary is in `secondaryComp`. Then here is some code to accomplish what you want:

```
Arrays.sort(mylist, secondaryComp);  // This must come first!
Arrays.sort(mylist, primaryComp);
```

Answer (score 7):

assuming your class is

```
class X {
    String name;
    int num;
}
```

then sorting will be

```
Arrays.sort(x, new Comparator<X>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(X o1, X o2) {
            if (o1.name.equals(o2.name)) {
                return Integer.compare(o1.num, o2.num);
            }
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }});
```

Answer (score -1):

Compare the second comparator first, and then the first comparator. I believe that should do the trick. You can create a class to do so.

```
class FullName {
    public String firstName;
    public String secondName;
}
```

Say you create a new name, called `BobBobbins`, assign values and then simple compare the second name first, and then the first name. You can have a static function to do the comparing:

```
public static bool compareTo ( FullName name1, FullName name2 ) {
    // Algorithm here
}
```

Should you use a static comparator, you can will have to do this : `FullName.compareTo( BobBobbins, CharlieChaplin );`